# How to modify bar width of google chart column?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

How I can modify the size of bar width of google chart column? I tried to add 'bar: { groupWidth: "20%" }' but it does nothing to the chart.

[image]

I really wanted it to make it thinner.

Here is the code that I want to use from google chart:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the width of only one column or all of them?

Comment: @testing_22 All of them

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart),

> The Material Charts are in beta. The appearance and interactivity are largely final, but many of the options available in Classic Charts are **not** yet available in them. You can find a list of options that are not yet supported in [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143).

One of these options is the `bar.groupWidth`, which seems to not have support yet.

In this case, since you are working with a group of bars and there's only one array of information in `data`:

```
['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
```

then that option doesn't seem to work. However, if there were **two** or more groups, it seemed to render but in a limited way. This said, I was able to find some workarounds, each one with its own positive aspects and drawbacks.

#### Change from Material Charts to Classical Charts

Here you have to reconstruct the chart's code following the Classical one

- Pros: options fully supported
- Cons: you will change from Material Charts to Classical Charts

```js
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Type', 'Financial status',{ role: "style" }],
        ["Sales", 1030, "#4285f4"],
        ["Expenses", 540, "#db4437"],
        ["Profit", 350, "f4b400"],
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      
    var options = {
        title: "Company Performance",
        subtitle: "Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2017",
        width: 600, // chart width
        bar: { groupWidth: "45%" },  // width of bars here
        legend: { position: "none" },
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

#### Separate that only group of bars into single bars

Put that only group bar in different arrays and adapt your labels

- Pros: the width will indeed change from 0 to 100% in `groupWidth`
- Cons: looses colored bars

```js
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Type', 'Financial status'],
        ["Sales", 1030],
        ["Expenses", 540],
        ["Profit", 350],
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2017',
        },
        bar: { groupWidth: '50%' }, // change width here
        width: 600, // width of the chart
        height: 400 // height of the chart
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}

google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;">
```

#### Use meaningless arrays

Put the array of information in the middle of two other meaningless arrays so
that you center your main data and gives the impression

- Pros: still uses the Material Chart design
- Cons: stretches the bars, doesn't provide space between bars

```js
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
        [' ', 0, 0, 0], // meaningless
        ['2017', 1030, 540, 350],
        [' ', 0, 0, 0] // meaningless
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2017',
        },
        bar: { groupWidth: '90%' }, // change width of bar here,
        width: 600, // width of the chart
        height: 400, // height of the chart
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;">
```

Comment: Thankyou for creative answer man. I forget to mention on my question that colors are important because it may have multiple set of data because the my system i working on is dynamic. So it is important to have different colors each data to easily identify it. Anyway your answer have a great help for me when it comes to in counter same issue that applicable your answer. it will help me a lot. Thankyou again.